# Is there a way to use an async check function for discord.py wait_for?

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

I want a method to change

```
async def check(reaction, user):
   await x
   return y

await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)
```

This yields an error message that says the check function isn't awaited:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.boost' raised an error: SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function
```

If I change the code to:

```
async def check(reaction, user):
   await x
   return y
await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=await check)
```

I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: object function can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Is there any way to have an async check function? Thanks!the current help command to acustom command, in my bot using discord.py

Comment: use `check` for discord 1.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import asyncio
@...
async def your_command(ctx, ...):

    async def run():
        # you can use await there
        return ...


    def check(msg):
        result = asyncio.create_task(run()) # run the async function
        return resul

    ctx = client.wait_for("message", check=check)
```

and there is an example:

```py
import asyncio

@client.command()
async def test(ctx):

    async def run(msg):
        await msg.send("This message is not yours!", hidden=True)
        return


    def check(msg):

        if msg.author.id == ctx.author.id:
            return True
        else:
            asyncio.create_task(run(msg))
            return False

    ctx = await client.wait_for("raw_reaction_add", check=check)

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

From delving into the code (on discord.py 1.5.1), there does not appear to be a way to use a coroutine as your check function. There might be a hacky workaround that exists, but it would not be best practice and would lead to a lot more problems than you would solve by implementing it. If you want to utilize `check`, just write a synchronous version of the function that executes the check, and make sure to make it as efficient as possible to keep from blocking.